# Add-1 laplace smoothing for bigram implementation

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram, smoothing

I am doing an exercise where I am determining the most likely corpus from a number of corpora when given a test sentence. I am trying to test an and-1 (laplace) smoothing model for this exercise.  I generally think I have the algorithm down, but my results are very skewed. I am aware that and-1 is not optimal (to say the least), but I just want to be certain my results are from the and-1 methodology itself and not my attempt.

Now, the And-1/Laplace smoothing technique seeks to avoid 0 probabilities by, essentially, taking from the rich and giving to the poor. Therefore, a bigram that is found to have a zero probability becomes:

```
 1/V, V=the number of types
```

This means that the probability of every other bigram becomes:

```
 P(B|A) = Count(W[i-1][W[i])/(Count(W[i-1])+V)
```

You would then take a sentence to test and break each into bigrams and test them against the probabilities (doing the above for 0 probabilities), then multiply them all together to get the final probability of the sentence occurring.

I am implementing this in Python. My code looks like this, all function calls are verified to work:

```
 #return is a counter of tuples containing ngrams: {('A','B'):C} 
 #this means ('A','B') means (B|A) in probabilistic terms 
 bigrams[0]=getBigrams(corpus[0]) 
 ... 
 bigrams[n]=getBigrams(corpus[n]) 

 #return is a dictionary of the form P['A']=C 
 unigrams[0]=getUnigrams(corpus[0]) 
 ... 
 unigrams[N]=getUnigrams(corpus[n]) 

 #generate bigram probabilities, return is P('A','B')=p, add one is done 
 prob[0]=getAddOneProb(unigrams[0],bigrams[0]) 
 ... 
 prob(n)=getAddOneProb(unigrams[n],bigrams[n]) 

 for sentence in test: 
      bi=getBigrams(sentence) 
      uni=getUnigrams(sentence) 
      P[0]=...=P[n]=1 #set to 1 
      for b in bi: 
           tup=b 
           try: 
                P[0]*=prob[tup] 
           except KeyError: 
                P[0]=(1/len(unigrams[0]) 
           #do this for all corpora
```

At the then I would compare all corpora, P[0] through P[n] and find the one with the highest probability

My results aren't that great but I am trying to understand if this is a function of poor coding, incorrect implementation, or inherent and-1 problems.

Comment: What is your question? Do you need help implementing it?

Comment: can't comment on the code - it's a very weak form of smoothing anyways.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, I'll encourage you to ask the question here in the discussion instead https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions. Most probably the questions would be flagged as "asking for tool/fix recommendation" as it is now.